# Placing a div inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a DIV element into a table cell, in a way in which the `<div>` spreads along all the cell's area. But, for unknown reason, a 1px `border` appears; as far as I know, it's neither part of the table or the div (table has no borders, padding or spacing, and the div has no margin or padding). Perhaps you can spot me the bug?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #arrow {
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-width: 100px 0px 100px 50px;
        border-color: blue blue blue red;
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-style: none;
        padding: 0px;
        spacing: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="red">
          Blah,
        </td>
    <td>
      <div id="arrow"><!----></div>
    </td>
        <td bgcolor="blue">
          blah.
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

-- or --

```
td { padding:0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS property is "border-spacing" instead of "spacing"

In addition I reset tables using

```
outline: 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Add styling for the table cell(s):

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #arrow {
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-width: 100px 0px 100px 50px;
        border-color: blue blue blue red;
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-style: none;
        padding: 0px;}

        td  { padding:0; border:0;}

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="red">
          Blah,
        </td>
    <td>
      <div id="arrow"><!----></div>
    </td>
        <td bgcolor="blue">
          blah.
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I gave the correct answer to Abraham Pinzur, as he responded earlier, but thanks anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. I should have mentioned that a good thing to do with your css is reset the browser styles first off. Check out http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html for a great example.