# Multiple div tags in table for specific text box lengths

Tags: php, html, css, input, html-table

I have a table with several different `<input type = 'text'>`. Some should be 64 characters long, some 7 character, and some 4 characters. Luckily, they are all grouped together so I figured the best way to do this would be multiple div tags for each section. However, when I attempt to adjust the width in the CSS, none of the inputs change. What gives? I have an external CSS. The table code and the CSS code are below

On a side note, I am aware that 64px != 64 characters

EDIT: Fixed for working html code.

The table:

```
<?php
    require_once('auth.php');
    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');
  ?>

    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Edit Profile</title>
        <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'default.css' />
      </head>
    <body>
      <div id = 'sideContainer'>
        <div id = 'navMain'>
          <?php include 'sidebar.html'; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id = 'content'>
        <?php
          $memberID = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
          $query = "SELECT * FROM memberData WHERE member_ID = '$memberID'";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $vCode = $row['vCode'];
            $keyID = $row['keyID'];
            $mlYeild = $row['mlYeild'];
            $cycleTime = $row['cycleTime'];
            $veld = $row['veld'];
            $scor = $row['scor'];
            $pyro = $row['pyro'];
            $plag = $row['plag'];
            $omber = $row['omber'];
            $kern = $row['kern'];
            $jas = $row['jas'];
            $hemo = $row['hemo'];
            $gneiss = $row['gneiss'];
            $ochre = $row['ochre'];
            $spod = $row['spod'];
            $crok = $row['crok'];
            $bistot = $row['bistot'];
            $ark = $row['ark'];
            $merc = $row['merc'];

          }
        ?>
        <form id = 'editPlayerInfo' name = 'editPlayerInfo' method = 'post' action = 'editUser-exec.php'>
          <table border = '0'>
            <tr>
              <td colspan = '2'><h2>API stuff</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h3>vCode</h3></td>
              <td><div id = 'vCode'><input type = 'text' name = 'vCode' value = '1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678'></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h3>keyID</h3></td>
              <td><div id = 'keyID'><input name = 'keyID' type = 'text' value = '<?php echo $keyID; ?>'></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <HR>
          <div id = 'refining'>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td colspan  = '4'><h2>Mining Laser stuff</h2></td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td><h3>Mining Laser Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'mlYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'mlYeild' value = '<?php echo $mlYeild; ?>'/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><h3>Cycle Time</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'cycleTime' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'cycleTime' value = '<?php echo $cycleTime; ?>'/></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <HR>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td colspan  = '6'><h2>Yeild Specifics</h2></td>
              </tr>
                <td><h3>Veldspar Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'veldYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'veldYeild' value = '<?php echo $veld; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Scordite Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'scorYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'scorYeild' value = '<?php echo $scor; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Pyroxeres Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'pyroYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'pyroYeild' value = '<?php echo $pyro; ?>'/></td>            
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><h3>Plagioclase Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'plagYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'plagYeild' value = '<?php echo $plag; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Omber Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'omberYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'omberYeild' value = '<?php echo $omber; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Kernite Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'kernYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'kernYeild' value = '<?php echo $kern; ?>'/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><h3>Jaspet Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'jasYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'jasYeild' value = '<?php echo $jas; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Hemorphite Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'hemYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'hemYeild' value = '<?php echo $hemo; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Gneiss Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'gneissYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'gneissYeild' value = '<?php echo $gneiss; ?>'/></td>          
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><h3>Dark ochre Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'ochreYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'ochreYeild' value = '<?php echo $ochre; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Spodumain Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'spodYield' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'spodYield' value = '<?php echo $spod; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Crokite Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'crokYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'crokYeild' value = '<?php echo $crok; ?>'/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><h3>Bistot Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'bisYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'bisYeild' value = '<?php echo $bistot; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Arkonor Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'arkYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'arkYeild' value = '<?php echo $ark; ?>'/></td>
                <td><h3>Mercoxit Yeild</h3></td>
                <td><input name = 'mercYeild' type = 'text' class = 'textfield' id = 'mercYeild' value = '<?php echo $merc; ?>'/></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table align = 'center'>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = 'submit' value = 'Make Changes'></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The CSS

```
  #sideContainer {float:left;}
#content {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#content table {
  border-spacing:10;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
#content h1 {
  vertical-align:top;
  height:40px; overflow:;
  color: #99CC00;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 0px 3px;
  font: bold 18px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #E6E8ED;
}
#content h2 {
  vertical-align:top;
  height:40px; overflow:;
  color: #336622;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 0px 3px;
  font: bold 24px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #E6E8ED;
}
#content h3 {
  text-align:bottom;
  height:30px; overflow:;
  color: #99CC00;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 0px 3px;
  font: bold 18px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #E6E8ED;
}
#content th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}
#content a {
  color: #2D3954;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#content a:hover {
  color: #99CC00;
}
#userTable input{
  vertical-align:center;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px 0px 3px;
  background: #ccffaa;
}
#vCode input{
  width: 10px;
}
#keyID input{
  width:100px;
}
#refining input{
  width:50px;
}


#sideTable {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}



.err {
  color: #FF9900;
}

#navMain {
  margin-left:25px;
  color:#c3c3c3;
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#navMain h2{
  font-family:Trebuchet MS1, Helvetica, sans-serif;
} /*Change font of the title*/


#navMain ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  margin-left:25px;
  font-size:15;
  margin-right:20px;
} /*Reset the default padding/margin and set it as required*/


#navMain ul li a{
  font-size:15;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#c3c3c3;
} /*Change color of link text and remove underline*/


#navMain ul li a:hover{
  color:#e0993e;
} /*Change color of hover text*
```

sidebar.html

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="editUser-form.php">Edit Personal Info</a></li>
<li><a href="sellToCorp-form.php">Sell to Corp</a></li>
<li><a href="fleet-form.php">Fleet Log Parser</a></li>
<li><a href="theoreticalMining.php">Theoretical Mining</a></li>
<li><a href="theoreticalRefining.php">Theoretical Refining</a></li>
<li><a href="corpMail-form.php">Send Corp Mail - N/A</a></li>
<li><a href="setCorpRate-form.php">Set Corp Rate</a></li>
<li><a href="updateSkillList.php">Update Skills</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a valid HTML table.

You should have `div` elements inside `td` element and then style the inputs. It is not valid to add `<div>` before `tr` element.

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jMqKe/) | | [***Updated Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jMqKe/1/)

```
<div id = 'content'>
    some content is here
    <div id = 'userTable'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>table header</th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div id = 'chars64'><input type = 'text' value = '1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678'></div></td>
                    <td><div id = 'chars64'><input type = 'text' value = '1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678'></div></td>
                    <td><div id = 'chars64'><input type = 'text' value = '1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678'></div></td>
                    <td><div id = 'chars64'><input type = 'text' value = '1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678'></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div id = 'chars7'><input type = 'text' value = '1234567'</div</td>
                    <td><div id = 'chars7'><input type = 'text' value = '1234567'</div</td>
                    <td><div id = 'chars7'><input type = 'text' value = '1234567'</div</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div id = 'chars4'><input type = 'text' value = '0.123'></div></td>
                    <td><div id = 'chars4'><input type = 'text' value = '0.123'></div></td>
                    <td><div id = 'chars4'><input type = 'text' value = '0.123'></div></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that makes sense. I slightly edited my table above. If there are multiple entries for the chars4 div, how would that work?

Comment: I can, I just wasn't sure if I'd have to retype the div for each one. That is unfortuante. That being said, after making the adjustments to the HTML, they still aren't changing their width...

Comment: hey, buddy they are working see the updated fiddle and copy & paste my code to your working document.

Comment: Damn. I have edited my question once again to include my full code, not shrunk down for simplicities sake, as the problem must lie somewhere that I can't for the life of me find.

Comment: can you explain the problem briefly?

Comment: I doubt I can put it into words. but with the css and code as seen above, this is what the page displays http://i.imgur.com/0AJox.png

Comment: what is in that sidebar.html? you may linked styles there also which will be overriding this one! see this working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/JgThH/

Comment: added code for that as well. I just can't figure out why it works in jsfiddle but not for me. who knows. i'll just let it live i suppose

Comment: that css in your question is in `default.css`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your div's inside your td tags. Something like this :

```
<div id='content'>some content is here
  <div id='userTable'>
    <table>
  <tr>
    <th>table header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='chars64'>
        <input type='text' value='1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='chars7'>
        <input type='text' value='1234567'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='chars4'>
        <input type='text' value='0.123'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the jsfiddle for it : http://jsfiddle.net/TM5Mk/

you can also refer to these previous discussions :

[div inside table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974573/div-inside-table)
[Placing a div inside a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522492/placing-a-div-inside-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because your HTML is wrong. You can put `<table>` elements in `<div>`. Just wrap the input in `<div>` .. not the entire `<tr>`. Here is:

```
<div id = "content">
    some content is here
    <div id = "userTable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>table header</th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <div id = "chars64">
                            <input type = "text" value = "1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678">
                        </div>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <div id = "chars7">
                            <input type = "text" value = "1234567">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        <div id = "chars4">
                            <input type = "text" value = "0.123"> 
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```